# Cannot cast to clientContext.CastTo<T> (Managed Client Object Model)

Tags: list, client-object-model, column

I am writing a method that is supposed to create a SharePoint list field. I want to be able to make my method return the newly created field. The problem that I am facing is that `list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(...)` (that is the Client Object Model's method that calls the creation of field in SharePoint) returns an object of type `Field`. I want, however, to cast to particular field type and that casting doesn't work.

Here's the method:

```
public T GetField<T>(ClientContext clientContext, string field title, FieldType type)
{
    Field field;

    // The following method creates a specific field and returns the Field object
    // but I want to cast it later on to get the more specific field class, e.g. 'FieldText'
    field = CreateMyField(type, field);

    // The following cast won't work because of the 'T'
    return clientContext.CastTo<T>(field);
}
```

I am getting the compile error

> The type `'T'` cannot be used as type parameter `'T'` in the generic type or method 
>   `'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.CastTo<T>(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObject)'`. 
>   There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from `'T'` to `'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObject'`

If I use a concrete class instead of the `T`, e.g. `FieldText`, the cast works like a charm.

My question is: Is there a way to make the cast work with generics? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some poking around I came across this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383970%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). It made me realize that I need to change my method's signature from:

```
public T GetField<T>(ClientContext clientContext, string field title, FieldType type)
```

to

```
public T GetField<T>(ClientContext clientContext, string field title, FieldType type)
    where T : ClientObject
```

This makes the cast work. Hooray!